# асинхронный перебор строки

Tags: массивы, многопоточность, swift

нужно перебрать массив строк через async при помощи 2х функций
на выходе должен получится первоначальный порядок

```
func stringProccesing( _array: [String]) -> [String]{
}

func doSomething(string: String, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
}
```

не получается передать данные в completion, что он принимает и зачем нужен?
если передавать строку, то выдает ошибку Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type '(String) -> Void'

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно передать в `completion` кусок кода, который будет выполняться, так как `(String) -> Void` - это [замыкание](https://swiftbook.ru/content/languageguide/closures/)

Здесь Вам нужно использовать `completion` так:

(пример без соблюдения логики)

```
func stringProccesing(_ array: [String]) -> [String] {
    let string = array[0]
    doSomething(string: string) { stringAfterDoSomething /*тип String*/ in 
       print(stringAfterDoSomething)
    }
}
```